# Adding permissions to jar, results in class not found exception

Tags: java, jar, permissions

In Oracle forms 11gR2 when connecting to the server through web browser - i.e. chrome - to run Oracle Forms it runs the following jar file `frmall.jar`
After updating Java instead of opening ,I got the following message.

```
Your Security settings have blocked an application from running due to missing a 
"Permissions" manifest attribute in the main jar.
```

I looked around and found that to add the missing attribute "Permission: all-permissions", I have to execute the following code in a cmd

```
jar -ufm frmall.jar mf.txt
```

where mf.txt contains "Permission: all-permissions".
Running the application again after restarting code the following error.
I kept looking and didn't find an answer.

How to solve it ?.
[image: error displayed]

Comment: you added all permissions correct? sometimes you have to use a .policy file as well

Comment: what do you mean by policy file ? what to add?  and where to find it ?

Comment: Have you tried clicking Details to see if that gives any clues

Comment: nothing shows when pressing details

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html

Comment: checked the default policy and set the permissions in CodeBase<ALL> to all permissions `grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};` , nothing happened. still class not found